# How implement a recursive version of this function

Tags: c, recursion, data-structures, heapsort

I need to implement a recursive version of this function:

```
static void peneira (int m, int v[]) {
    int f=2, t;
    while(f<=m){
        count_Iteracoes_HeapSort++;
        if(f<m && v[f] < v[f+1])++f;
        if(v[f/2] >= v[f]) break;
        t = v[f/2]; v[f/2] = v[f]; v[f] = t;
        f *= 2;
    }

}
```

I was doing something like this:

```
static void peneiraRec(int m,int v[]){
    count_Iteracoes_HeapSort++;
    int f=2,t;
    if(m<=1) {
        return;
    }
    while(f<=m) {
        peneiraRec(m - 1, v);
        if (f < m && v[f] < v[f + 1]) ++f;
        if (v[f / 2] >= v[f]) break;
        t = v[f / 2];v[f / 2] = v[f];v[f] = t;
        f *= 2;
    }
}
```

But this is not working. Can anyone help me?

This function is a auxiliar function of heap sort. I will post all the code

```
 static void 
constroiHeap (int m, int v[])
{
   int k; 
   for (k = 1; k < m; ++k) {                   
      // v[1..k] é um heap
      int f = k+1;
      while (f > 1 && v[f/2] < v[f]) {  // 5
         troca (v[f/2], v[f]);          // 6
         f /= 2;                        // 7
      }
   }
}

static void peneira (int m, int v[]) {
    int f=2, t;
    while(f<=m){
        count_Iteracoes_HeapSort++;
        if(f<m && v[f] < v[f+1])++f;
        if(v[f/2] >= v[f]) break;
        t = v[f/2]; v[f/2] = v[f]; v[f] = t;
        f *= 2;
    }

}

void
heapsort (int n, int v[])
{
   int m;
   constroiHeap (n, v);
   for (m = n; m >= 2; --m) {
      troca (v[1], v[m]);
      peneira (m-1, v);
   }
}
int main{
  int v0[6] = {0,63726,2323,0,32,236723};
  heapsort_rec(5, v0);
}
```

Output : v0 = 0,32,2323,63726,236723

Basically, I need my input is a sorted array and the output should be the array ordely.

I need to implement this peneira function in a recursive away

Comment: Can you give some information about the purpose of this function?

Comment: Is it a homework or similar?

Comment: Show the context, show how the function is supposed to be used, define the purpose, give sample input, i.e. make a [mcve], take the [tour] for some pretty decoration of your profile.

Comment: Aside: `v[f+1]` looks suspicious when `f` can be equal to `m`.

Answer (score 2):

Any loop can be made recursive by turning the body of the loop into a function that takes the loop variable as an argument (in addition to the variables used inside the loop).  The function first tests the loop variable to see if the bound has been reached, and returns if it has.  Otherwise, it performs one iteration of the loop, and then calls itself with the new value of the loop variable.  Typically, you will need two functions; the recursive step function, and another function to call the recursive step with the initial value of the loop variable.

```
static void peneira_rec (int f, int m, int v[]) {
    int t;
    if(f > m) return; // exit loop

    count_Iteracoes_HeapSort++;
    if(f<m && v[f] < v[f+1])++f;
    if(v[f/2] >= v[f]) return; // exit loop
    t = v[f/2]; v[f/2] = v[f]; v[f] = t;
    peneira_rec(f*2, m, v); // loop again
}

static void peneira (int m, int v[]) {
    peneira_rec(2, m, v); // start the loop
}
```

Comment: I made the function with a while to prevent a creation of another function. Do you think this way is better?

Comment: The whole point of making the function recursive is to replace the while loop

Comment: I understand the point now, i had removed the while loop and it's working perfectly

Comment: Can you click the check mark next to the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

First of all why do you call peneiraRec with m-1 as its first argument. In the non recursive implementation m doesn't change,only f does. Secondly, every time you call your function f is set to 2 and you don't want that. You want f to be 2 time its previous value. And third why use head recursion instead of tail. My suggestion is to change the definition of peneiraRec to peneiraRec (int m, int v[], int f ). The first time you will need this call it with f = 2 aw its third parameter and after that call it recursively as peneiraRec (m ,v ,2*f).

Answer (score 0):

I did somenting like this after cgss answer

```
void peneiraRec(int m,int v[], int f){
    count_Iteracoes_HeapSort++;
    int t;
    if(f>m){
        return;
    }
    if(f<m && v[f] < v[f+1])++f;
    if(v[f/2] >= v[f]) return;
    t = v[f/2]; v[f/2] = v[f]; v[f] = t;
    peneiraRec(m,v,f*2);
}

void heapsort_rec(int n, int v[]){
    int m;
    constroiHeap (n, v);
    for (m = n; m >= 2; --m) {
        count_Iteracoes_HeapSort;
        int t=v[1]; v[1]=v[m]; v[m]=t;
        peneiraRec (m-1, v,2);
    }
}
```

And it's working, I think I did it. I was not seeing what was in my face, only `f` was changing not `m`, really thank you guys and sorry for my stupid explanation, I'm new on stackoverflow.

Comment: That's wrong.  When the first recursive step returns, the entire algorithm is done, yet the while loop will keep iterating.  You may just be lucky that your loop body is idempotent so those subsequent iterations find nothing to do.  But for a non-idempotent operation, this would give the wrong result.

Comment: It's identical to my answer now (except for the order of the arguments), so I would say it is right!  However, my previous comment now make no sense in relation to this new code.

Comment: Thanks man!! Your first comment was uploaded when I was editing the answer haha, btw Thank you!